# Visual Studio Installer Project Uses Old Installer

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-services, visual-studio-setup-proje

I'm using the Visual Studio Installer [Project](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects) to install some C# Windows Services.

I now want to update the installer to do some new things for users who try to install on a computer where my services already exist.

I keep the `UpgradeCode` the same, create a new version and a new `ProductCode`. This allows the installation to start even though it already exists.

The problem is that the setup uses the *old* installer to do the installation. Once I uninstall, the setup uses my new installer code. But I want it to use the new code while it's already installed.

How do I get the setup to ignore the installer that the program originally used and to use my new installer code?

Comment: Are the `PackageCode` values between the two the same? Or different? Probably because they are the same in both, Windows is treating it as uninstalling the original, which is cached somewhere deep in its system.

Comment: I was unaware of the `PackageCode` value as it's not an option in the VisualStudio properties, but the codes are different. I tried changing the code too. Still using the old installer.

Comment: What exactly does "using the old installer" mean? Are you seeing the Repair/Uninstall dialog? Is the upgrade failing? Error messages?